# Backbone allow duplicates in collection

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to have duplicates in my collection

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var collection = new Collection({});

var model1 = new Model({idk: 1, name: "pete"})
var model2 = new Model({idk: 2, name: "phil"})

collection.add(model1);
collection.add(model2);
collection.add(model1);
```

When I call `console.log(collection.toJSON())` it logs out only an array with 2 model objects, and some empty object for reason. Is there any way I can make my collection accept duplicates?

Comment: id is a special property for Backbone models. Is it possible to map your id property to something else, like - my_id?

Comment: hmm yeah that worked, but accually I needed to specify the problem differently, I just edited my post above.

Comment: Well, a Backbone collection is a set and from the documentation:  _Instead of throwing an error when adding duplicate models to a collection, Backbone will now silently skip them instead._ Maybe you can give more details on why you need duplicate objects in this collection?

Comment: Thanks. I did it this way: instead of calling collection.add(model1), I call collection.add(model1.toJSON()). Your idea from the prev comment was helpful, I can't have same 'id' properties in that json data!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, the empty model/object is a result of passing an emply object to the Backbone.Collection.constructor.

```
> var collection = new Backbone.Collection({});
> collection.length;
=> 1
```

Next, each Backbone.Model keeps a reference to its collection (using the collection property) and hence you *cannot* duplicate a model in the collection. Instead you can duplicate the model properties by doing the following:

```
> var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
> var model = new Backbone.Model({ foo: 'bar' });
> collection.add(model);
> collection.add(model.toJSON());
> collection.length;
=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
collection.add(model1);
```

call

```
collection.add(model1.toJSON());
```

Can't have any 'id' properties in the model though, it won't duplicate then.